# Displaying vectors on Screen

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, nested-loops, iostream

I have been doing some reading about how to create a set number of arrays and populate those arrays using for loops in C++. Everywhere says that I need to use vectors. I have created the arrays and populated them using vectors (I think). When I compile and run with displaying the arrays, everything is ok. When I try to display the contents of the arrays, The program compiles ok but crashes when I run it.

I am trying to create 100 arrays with their size increasing by 500 elements each time. (This is for an assignment where we need to test the efficacy of an algorithm.)

```
unsigned int numArrays = 100;
unsigned int arraySize = 0;
//Create holder variable:
unsigned int randomInt = 0;
//Create the arrays:
std:vector<std::vector<int> > arrays(numArrays);

for(std::size_t i=0; i< numArrays; i++){

    arraySize = i * 500;
    vector<int> temp;
    temp.reserve(arraySize);

    for(int j=0; j< arraySize; j++){

        //Generate Random number:
        randomInt = rand();
        //Add the number to the array:
        temp.push_back(randomInt);

    }
    arrays.push_back(temp);
}


for(int i=0; i<arrays.size(); i++){

    cout << "{";
    for(int j=0; j<arrays.at(i).size() - 1; j++){

        cout << arrays.at(i).at(j) << ",";

    }
    cout << arrays.at(i).back() << "}" << endl;
}
```

I assume the error is somewhere in the final nested loops but I am not sure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing stands out at me straight away. But have you perhaps tried debugging the program? using gdb? You should be able to run it and then backtrace to where the error occured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std:vector<std::vector<int> > arrays(numArrays);
```

Here you initialize your vector with `numArrays` empty `vector<int>`s.
But then you **append** your new vectors. Meaning you have at the end `2*numArrays` vectors.

The crash comes from the first half of the vectors:

- the minus 1 in `j<arrays.at(i).size() - 1`: `size()` returns an unsigned 0, minus 1 is the maximum value.
- `arrays.at(i).back()` trying to get a non existing last element.

To fix the problem, replace this line

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > arrays(numArrays);
```

by

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > arrays;
arrays.reserve(numArrays);
```

And add a test for non-`empty()`ness before computing `size() - 1`.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. How do I fix this problem? I tired removing that line but it still crashed. (I am extremely new to C++)

Comment: @ChristopherLittlewood Change this line `std:vector<std::vector<int> > arrays(numArrays);` to this `std:vector<std::vector<int> > arrays;`. The program will close because an exception will be thrown from `std::vector<T>::at()`, and incidentally you have made no attempt to catch such an exception. However I do not beleive you will need to. Just make the suggested change and it should work.